# How to move an entity to the mouse position, rotating towards it

Tags: javascript, html

I was reading [this](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-smoothly-move-an-entity-to-the-position-of-the-mouse--gamedev-7356) article on tuts+ on how to make a spaceship follow the cursor using CreateJS,
and i was wondering how can i make the entity move towards the mouse position but rotate facing it too.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gamedevtuts/nkZjR/) of the example without rotation
and the code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
var ship;
var stage;
var assets;
var loader;
var serverString = "http://source.tutsplus.com/gamedev/authors/JamesTyner/SmoothMoves/";
var stageHeight = 600;
var stageWidth = 600;
var shipHeight = 64;
var shipWidth = 64;
var easingAmount = 0.15;
var text;
stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
assets = [];
manifest = [{
    src: serverString + "ship.png",
    id: "character"
}];

loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
loader.onComplete = handleComplete;
loader.onFileLoad = handleFileLoad;
loader.loadManifest(manifest);

function handleFileLoad(event) {
    var id = event.item.id;
    var result = loader.getResult(id);
    ship = new createjs.Bitmap(result);
    ship.x = (stageWidth / 2) - shipWidth;
    ship.y = stageHeight - shipHeight;
    ship.regX = shipWidth/2;
    ship.regY = shipHeight/2;
}

function handleComplete() {
    stage.addChild(ship);
    text = new createjs.Text("Click To Activate", "20px Arial", "#000000");
    text.x = 200;
    text.y = stageHeight / 2;
    stage.addChild(text);
    stage.update();
}

stage.onMouseDown = function () {
    stage.removeChild(text);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);
};

function tick(event) {
   var xDistance = stage.getStage().mouseX - ship.x;
   var yDistance = stage.getStage().mouseY - ship.y;
   var distance = Math.sqrt(xDistance * xDistance + yDistance * yDistance);
    if (distance > 1) {
        ship.x += xDistance * easingAmount;
        ship.y += yDistance * easingAmount;
    }
    stage.update();
}
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First calculate the angle between the ship and the mouse pointer in degrees:

```
var mousePointerPosition = {
        x: stage.getStage().mouseX,
        y: stage.getStage().mouseY
    };

var spaceShipPosition = {
        x: ship.x,
        y: ship.y
    };

var angle = Math.atan2(
        spaceShipPosition.y - mousePointerPosition.y,
        spaceShipPosition.x - mousePointerPosition.x
    ) * 180 / Math.PI;
```

Then rotate the spaceship:

```
ship.rotation = ( angle > 180 ? -angle : angle ) + 90;
```

If `angle` is over 180, we invert the angle to make the ship turn the other direction. Also I added `+ 90` to the angle because the ship is turned 90 degrees compared to the mouse position.

Js Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nkZjR/200/

Comment: Thanks Mate. smart solution. appreciate it. If i could Vote Up, i whould